# Applet Java в firefox

Tags: java, браузер

написал на Java Applet вставил его на свою верстку index.html
в результате Оперу очень сильно грузит иногда зависает, а вот мазила вообще не отображает. Только Сафара нормально отображает скрипт.
Подскажите как решить эту проблему что бы скрипт отображался в браузерах

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего в FireFox выключена поддержка Java плагина. Инструкция по проверке Java плагина для Firefox [здесь](http://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20Java-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20Firefox)

P.S. Пишите грамотно, а то прямо срамота...